# Formulae field is not showing correct value in debug logs as expected.

Tags: formula-field, debugging

I have create a formula field with decimal places 1. Formula field return type is currency.

If i see its value by querying the data base using developer console i get `15000` but if i put a debug log in developer console to log its value i get `15997.0` and this `15997.0` value is being used in further calculations. I am not getting any clue why is this being happen.
Can anybody explain why it this being happen? Why developer console
showing wrong value in developer log?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you post your queries here once. Are you referring to correct fields in your query. Please check once.

Comment: I am referring to correct field. I have checked that

Comment: Without seeing some code that includes your formulas and your queries, I doubt that anyone here is going to have an answer for you that will be anything more than conjecture.

Comment: For the currency in question , how many decimal places are configured in the Currency setup?